# Get request returns 500. The routing in my MVC project seems to be correct, but I am unable to investigate further

Tags: http, model-view-controller, routes, http-status-code-500

I'm having a react app that performs a get request to my MVC app, and it works fine for most controllers/actions, but I have made a new one, and it only returns 500.
For testing I've just made some simple data to make sure it can connect. So an request Url like: "api/internal/v1/new/getsomestuff"

Like with the other controllers, it inherits from a base API controller which is like this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/internal/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), 400)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), 401)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), 403)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), 404)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), 409)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), 500)]
[Authorize(AuthPolicies.InternalApi.InternalApiPolicy)]
[BffApi]
public class InternalApiController: ControllerBase 
{
   // some stuff
}
```

Any I have my new controller:

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
public class NewController : InternalApiController
{

    public NewController()
    {
      // some stuff
    }

    [HttpGet("getsomestuff")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getsomestuff()
    {           
        return Ok("success");
    }

}
```

As I explained, this returns 500, and a breakpoint on the action is never hit. If I add this action to an existing controller and update the URI, it works. So I suspected that it was a problem with the routing. So I checked the startup.cs in the project, which contains this code:

```
  endpoints.MapControllers();
```

When I inspect it I see that my NewController has it's action registered, and the routing path is correct.

What should I do next? Have I missed something obvious? If not, how can I find out more?

Answer (score 0):

The routing was fine. There was a problem with the interface of the controller.